# In R, what's the average number of distinct events per ID in a dataframe?

Tags: r, dplyr, count, mean

**Background**

Here's an R dataframe `d`:

```
d <- data.frame(ID = c("a","a","a","a","a","a","b","b"),
                event = c("G12","R2","O99","B4","B4","A24","L5","J15"),
                stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

It looks like so:

[image: d]

You see 2 people represented by `ID`, each with >1 event. `ID`=*a* has 6 events but only 5 distinct ones, while `ID`=*b* has 2 events, both distinct.

**The Problem**

I'd like to calculate the average number of distinct / unique `event`s per person in `d`. In this case, the arithmetic goes like this:

(5 unique events + 2 unique events) / 2 distinct `ID`'s = **3.5** unique events per person, which is the answer I'm looking for.

**What I've tried**

I've attempted something like this so far:

```
d %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(mean = mean(tally(unique(event))))
```

But this throws an error.

Comment: Lol my bad, my math was wrong! It's very late here. Will correct in original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`n_distinct` would give you count of distinct events, you can calculate that per `ID` and then calculate the ratio.

```
library(dplyr)

d %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(distinct_event = n_distinct(event)) %>%
  summarise(ratio = mean(distinct_event))

#  ratio
#  <dbl>
#1   3.5
```

Answer (score 1):

**data.table**

```r
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)
df <- data.frame(ID = c("a","a","a","a","a","a","b","b"),
                event = c("G12","R2","O99","B4","B4","A24","L5","J15"),
                stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

setDT(df)[, list(uniqueN(event)), by = ID] %>% 
  .[, list(ratio = mean(V1))]
#>    ratio
#> 1:   3.5
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

We could do this in `base R`

```
mean(aggregate(event ~ ID, d, FUN = function(x) length(unique(x)))$event)
```

-output

```
[1] 3.5
```